# Looking for easy way to store data in cloud and access from remote android app

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm semi-new to android. I've been looking all over the internet, but I can't find a solution to my problem. I'm making an android app for my friend's band. I doubt they'll be getting more than a few views a day. I just need a dead simple way to store maybe three or four strings in the cloud and access those strings from my android app. It doesn't need to be complicated at all. Just a remote database. I've looked into GData, facebook, but it's all extremely complicated to set up. Can someone give me a preferably free solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/), it's very easy to use and let's you focus on your Android app, instead of having to create and manage the backend.

If not, probably start by serving up a JSON encoded file with your strings somewhere (on your own website) and work on getting this to your device using HttpClient, decode it and display. There should be many examples of this around (Google `android json httpclient`).

Comment: Very interesting! Certainly simpler than my alternative.

Comment: I'm going to try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install dropbox

create a txt file to store your strings.

save it in the public folder.

right click the txt file and choose dropbox->copy public link embed that link withion your app.

When you make an http request on that url you'll receive back whatever text is stored in the file at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that I am more inclined towards .NET, I would personally create an application in [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) containing a single web-service that provides this information.
AppHarbor provides free instances of SQL Server, MySQL, RavenDB, as well as several others free of charge.
Having a real back-end instead of just exposing the data gives you a bit more control I think.

But that is just one of hundreds of options to solve this problem I think. The same could be accomplished through an application in google apps, files in dropbox, or even consuming the data directly such as from publicly available google spreadsheets, or even public excel files through Excel Services and it's REST interface.

Comment: Will AppHarbor work with android?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. It's just as external service accessed through the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data central or per user?

### Centrally Defined

I recommend putting your data in a flat JSON format file or perhaps a single table MySQL database and spit it out in JSON via PHP all on a web server.

### Per Device

REST API. No shortcuts there. But one of your immediate problems will be some kind of unique user identifier, and that's where Facebook comes in. Honestly that SDK is quite straight forward, will take you about 4 hours first time around but could be much less.